# How do i get the content of a Hashtable keys/values write them to text file and read them back and update the Hashtable variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

This what i did now:

```
private Hashtable alreadyPost = new Hashtable();
        private void PostMessage()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]) && !alreadyPost.ContainsKey(ScrollLabel._lines[i]))
                    {
                        lineToPost = ScrollLabel._lines[i];
                        string testline = lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + ScrollLabel._lines[i + 1];
                        //PostFacebookWall(AccessPageToken, testline + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "נשלח באופן אוטומטי כניסיון דרך תוכנה");
                        alreadyPost.Add(lineToPost, true);
                        numberofposts += 1;
                        label7.Text = numberofposts.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < alreadyPost.Count; i++)
            {
                WritePostedAlready.WriteLine(alreadyPost[i]);
            }
            WritePostedAlready.Close();
        }
```

I added now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alreadyPost.Count; i++)
{
    WritePostedAlready.WriteLine(alreadyPost[i]);
}
WritePostedAlready.Close();
```

`WritePostedAlready` is `StreamWriter`.

What i want to do is to read from the `alreadyPost` the keys and values and write them to a text file in the format:

```
Key = Value
Key = Value
.
.
.
```

And then i want to read from the text file back each key and value and put them back into the `alreadyPost` variable.

Im calling the `PostMessage` in a timer every 10 seconds.
So i want to check what had already posted each time i run the program over again.

1. Read the keys and values once in the constructor when im running the program and if there are any exist keys and values update the `alreadyPost` variable read from the text file and add it to the `alreadyPost`.
2. In the method `PostMessage` to do the same thing.

Comment: So which specific piece are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it to work:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in alreadyPost)
            {
                WritePostedAlready.WriteLine(entry.Key + " = " + entry.Value);
            }
            WritePostedAlready.Close();

            alreadyPost = new Hashtable();
            List<string> readLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Temp\WritePostedAlready.txt").ToList();
            foreach (string line in readLines)
            {
                string key = line.Split('=')[0];
                string val = line.Split('=')[1];
                if (!alreadyPost.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    alreadyPost.Add(key, val);
                }
            }
```

Thanks.